# Consistent radius with `geom_spoke` in `ggplot2`

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

When plotting with geom_spoke, when the range of x and y axes differ drastically,
the radius of the spokes is not uniform across the angles.

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y=seq(10, 100, by=10))
df$angle <- seq(from=-pi, to=pi, length.out=10)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle), radius = 0.5)
```

[image]
How to ensure that the plotted length of spokes are uniform irrespective of angle ?

```
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y=seq(10, 100, by=10))
df$angle <- seq(from=-pi, to=pi, length.out=10)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle), radius = 0.5) + 
  coord_equal(ratio=1)
```

Use of coord_equal(ratio=1) makes the length of spokes the same, but makes the plot unreadable. Is there a workaround for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this plot is that your Y axis is 10 times the scale of the X axis.

You can change the y-axis to be on the same scale:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y/10)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_spoke(aes(angle = angle), radius = 0.5) + 
  coord_equal(ratio=1)
```

[image]

If you can't change the y-axis scale (which would not be surprising), then you may be stuck with generating your own radius with `sin`/`cos` on your data. And since you care about uniform radius sizing with all values of `angle`, you need to control the relatives x/y ranges/axis-scales.

I feel like this is not the best awesome/intuitive solution, tbh, but look at it from another point of view: the developer. If you want the radius of the spoke to be constant regardless of angle, then the `radius=` that you provide `0.5` must be interpreted as relative to one of the axes. It should now be obvious that a radius of 0.5 seems okay from the X perspective, but not from the Y perspective, so `radius=0.5` is in that sense *ambiguous*.